# Get yesterday's date from the date entered

Tags: c#, date, console-application

I have console application that accepts date as parameter. However, the date is passed as a string in this format:

```
string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Once the date is entered I need to programmatically get `day - 1` from the entered date. Since this is a string, I cannot do any calculation.

For example, user enters:

> 20141023

I need to subtract a day from the date to get:

> 20141022

I did a quick fix to solve my immediate need, however, this is not the right way to do it and it has a bug:

```
int yt = Int32.Parse(dt) - 1;
```

And then I turn around and convert it `yt.ToString()`

The above solution will not work if it's the `1st` of the month.

Is there a way I can programmatically get yesterday's date in the format `(yyyyMMdd)` without changing the format and possibly not using the `TimeSpan`?

Comment: Why is it a problem using `TimeSpan`?

Comment: Any particular reason you're against translating it into a standard `DateTime` object then doing `AddDays(-1)`? You'll get easy calendar parsing for leap years and other crazy things like that.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, it's not a problem. However, every time I deal with `TimeSpan` I run in into few issues. If it's the only way to go, I'm willing to look at few suggestions.

Comment: @StevenV, can you give me an example? I don't want to force the user to enter `DateTime`.

Comment: If you have any specific issues with `TimeSpan` why don't you ask about those instead of trying to work around using a type that was designed to do what you're asking?

Comment: but why dont you convert to datetime, add -1 days and then convert again to string? because if you do it this way there will be some date as 20139999..you could do datetime.now.adddays(-1).tostring("yyyyMMdd")..

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
  DateTime data = DateTime.ParseExact("20141023", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", data, data.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't parse the input into a `DateTime` object? Then you can use the `DateTime.AddDays(-1)`

For example:

```
var inputDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20141022", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // change "20141022" into the inputted value
var yesterday = inputDate.AddDays(-1);

var yesterdayString = yesterday.ToString("yyyyMMdd"); // this will be yesterdays date, in the string format
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you ?

```
string newDateTimeStr = (DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

EDIT:
for the date entered by the user:

```
string txtInputDate = Console.ReadLine();
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(txtInputDate).ToLocalTime();
string newDateTimeStr = (dateTime.AddDays(-1)).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: That will only return yesterday's date. I need to return yesterday's date from the date entered by user.

Comment: @Sam, ok - if you have a datepicker to set the date in a text input, then take the text input and set it as a datetime object.  Then the newDateTimeStr string is simple to delete a day and convert to string pretty much the same as my original answer

Comment: thank you for your help. But this is a `Console Application`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Is it just a case of Console.ReadLine() instead ?